# Does deleting a tradeline mean the account is wiped from credit report

Tags: debt-collection

A collections agency wrote:

> Within approximately 30 days of your final payment successfully posting, we will request that the three major credit reporting agencies delete our tradeline related to your account from your credit bureau report.

Does this mean the debt will be removed from my report? The statement came on a bill from the agency. Should I go ahead and pay or request a pay for delete letter in writing? Should it be on the original company's letterhead or is the collection agency fine?

Comment: How do you think that a "pay-for-delete" letter would be different from this written statement that says when your payment posts, they delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's great! It will be deleted from all 3 credit bureaus. That letter is good enough.

After you pay your last payment, call the company and let them know they are supposed to remove the account from your reports now

Then check your 3 reports about 45 days after you speak with them. If for some reason it still shows on a report, create a dispute on the account and upload that letter to the credit bureau.

It is usually really hard to get them to remove it from your report but you lucked out.